# Java SSL Certificate Cache - clear

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssl, jenkins, jetty

I'm using Jenkins and I just setup a new Atlassian Stash git repo using HTTPS. I want to get Stash and Jenkins talking (report build info). They dont now since enabling HTTPS on the Stash instance.

There was an error with the certificate (the wrong one was being used - i.e. cert for a different domain). This problem was corrected, all clients can connect including running a curl/wget from the box.

Jenkins is running on Ubuntu 14 with bundled Jetty server.

Whenever jenkins tries to connect to git.int.company.com it throws the following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <git.int.company.com> != <jira.int.company.com> OR <jira.int.compant.com> OR <www.jira.int.comapny.com>
```

This sounds like somewhere Java has cached the cert for git.int.company.com. I have tried restarting jenkins, restarting the box with no luck. How can I clear the SSL certificate cache in Java/Jenkins/Jetty?

Answer (score 1):

Bit old now, but at a guess you need to update the .csr referenced in the truststore

https://serverfault.com/questions/392879/clearing-java-certificates-cache-force-reload-certificates

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this `hostname in certificate didn't match` problem in a Jenkins environment because of an outdated Maven version, whose *HttpComponents* dependencies don't work with SNI SSL certificates.

Once I updated Maven (presumably anything better than Maven 3.2.5 should work), everything worked well again.